# Top hits bias in Google Site Search

Tags: google-site-search

I am considering implementing Google Site Search on a website. Unfortunately documentation on the features seems somewhat limited and `google.com/sitesearch` returns 404.

In my search I want to implement biasing on the top results, but cannot understand what is actually possible. So my question is whether the following is possible:

When a user searches for a given phrase, I want to ensure that a given page is returned as the top result. Please note that it is a page and there is only one site included in the search.
For example, imagine I search for "Yoga". I want to make sure that the page `/mypage` is the number one hit, even though it isn't optimized for "Yoga".

As an alternative, how can I implement it so that `/mypage` gets boosted a lot when searching for "Yoga"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to set up a Promotion.

In *Control Panel (`google.com/cse`) > Search Features > Promotions*,  set up "yoga" as **Promotion triggering queries** and `yoursite.com/mypage` as the promotion URL.

Here's more on promotions:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/promotions

Comment: Thanks. A couple of follow up questions:

1. Let us say searching for "yoga" will render /mypage in position 5. I then create a promotion for it, will the /mypage then appear twice (one as a promotion and one in fifth position)?

2. If a promotion is created, is it possible to make it look like the rest of the search results, meaning that it looks the same and that if the resultpage contains 0-9 hits, it will only show my promotion and 0-8 hits?

Thanks
Jens

Comment: Any ideas on this? It is fine that it is not possible, I just need to know.

Comment: Re 1) Easy to test, just give it a try:) Re 2) It will breach Terms of Service of Google Custom Search.